# Groupin multiple nodes and outputting under a common element in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

im currently trying to Group together multiple nodes with different values and output them under a common node.
below is my source document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<transfer>
   
    <UNH>
        <LIN>
            <LIN1>14</LIN1>
            <LIN3>
                <LIN3.0>6407890091936</LIN3.0>
                <LIN3.1>EN</LIN3.1>
            </LIN3>
        </LIN>
        <PIA>
            <PIA1>5</PIA1>
            <PIA2>
                <PIA2.0>9193</PIA2.0>
                <PIA2.1>SA</PIA2.1>
            </PIA2>
        </PIA>
        <IMD>
            <IMD1>F</IMD1>
            <IMD3>
                <IMD3.0 />
                <IMD3.1 />
                <IMD3.2 />
                <IMD3.3>somevalue</IMD3.3>
            </IMD3>
        </IMD>
        <MEA>
            <MEA1>AAE</MEA1>
            <MEA2>AAA</MEA2>
            <MEA3>
                <MEA3.0>KGM</MEA3.0>
                <MEA3.1>0,900</MEA3.1>
            </MEA3>
        </MEA>
        <QTY>
            <QTY1>
                <QTY1.0>12</QTY1.0>
                <QTY1.1>6</QTY1.1>
                <QTY1.2>PCE</QTY1.2>
            </QTY1>
        </QTY>
<LIN>
            <LIN1>16</LIN1>
            <LIN3>
                <LIN3.0>6407890091936</LIN3.0>
                <LIN3.1>EN</LIN3.1>
            </LIN3>
        </LIN>
        <PIA>
            <PIA1>5</PIA1>
            <PIA2>
                <PIA2.0>9193</PIA2.0>
                <PIA2.1>SA</PIA2.1>
            </PIA2>
        </PIA>
        <IMD>
            <IMD1>F</IMD1>
            <IMD3>
                <IMD3.0 />
                <IMD3.1 />
                <IMD3.2 />
                <IMD3.3>somevalue</IMD3.3>
            </IMD3>
        </IMD>
        <MEA>
            <MEA1>AAE</MEA1>
            <MEA2>AAA</MEA2>
            <MEA3>
                <MEA3.0>KGM</MEA3.0>
                <MEA3.1>12,00</MEA3.1>
            </MEA3>
        </MEA>
        <QTY>
            <QTY1>
                <QTY1.0>12</QTY1.0>
                <QTY1.1>8</QTY1.1>
                <QTY1.2>PCE</QTY1.2>
            </QTY1>
        </QTY>
    </UNH>
</transfer>
```

and what i want to do is create a `package` tag for each `LIN` element
and assign the values located in `IMD3.3,MEA3.1 and QTY1.1`to an element within the package node, and i need to do this for every LIN.

My issue is that im unsure how i can manage to get all the values belonging to the "correct" `LIN`  since they are not the Child nodes of `LIN`and i want to do this for every `LIN` element.

i have tried using position with xsl:for-each however it seems very inefficient and i want this to be used for any amount of `LIN` elements.

my desired output would be something like this:

```
<package>
<quantity>6</quantity>(value of QTY1.1 in the first occurence)
<weight>0,900</weight>(value of MEA3.1 where MEA3.0=KGM first occurence)
<text>somevalue></text>(the value of IMD3.3 first occurence)
</package>
<package>
<quantity>8</quantity>(value of QTY1.1 in the second occurence)
<weight>12,00</weight>(value of MEA3.1 where MEA3.0=KGM second occurence)
<text>somevalue2</text>(the value of IMD3.3 second occurence)
</package>
```

and so forth for every LIN.
Would muenchian grouping work here or should i use something entirerly different?

Comment: I  believe a simple `following-sibling::QTY[1]` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user michael.hor257k in the comments, the following-sibling:: syntax was sufficient to solve this problem.
thanks!